# expression must be a modifiable lvalue multiplying varibles

Tags: c

```
betamount * 1.5 = moneywon;
```

This is giving me the error "IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Why??

```
int hitorstay,total,dwtotal,crd,card1,card2,c,temp, moneyamount = 500,betamount,moneywon; 



int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

start:


    printf("How much would you like to bet on this hand: ");
    scanf("%d", &betamount);
    moneyamount -= betamount;
    puts("");
    int card1 = 2 + rand() % 11;
    int card2 = 2 + rand() % 11;
    total = card1 + card2;


    if (card1 + card2 == 21) {
        printf("YOU HAVE WON A BLACKJACK HAND WITH %d AND %d\n", card1, card2);
        betamount * 1.5 = moneywon; //this is where i get the error

        }
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: What are you asking? For the correct way of coding, or an explanation of why the C (and probably most other) language syntax is the way it is?

Answer (score 1):

`betamount * 1.5` is an rvalue. It can't be left operand of assignment operator.

C11-§6.5.16/2

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Comment: thanks, I always forget how important the order of the syntax is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to write

```
moneywon = betamount * 1.5;
```

The *target* of an assignment must always be the left-hand expression, and that expression must always be an *lvalue*; basically, an expression that refers to a region of memory such that the memory may be read from or written to (e.g., a variable name, an array element, a pointer dereference, etc.).

The result of `betamount * 1.5` is not an lvalue; it doesn't refer to any object in memory.  It's equivalent to assigning a new value to the constant `1`; it's a nonsensical operation.

Also, you've declared all of your variables of type `int`, meaning they can only store integer values.  If `betamount` is `5`, then the result stored in `moneywon` will be `7`, not `7.5`.  If you want to be able to store fractional values, you must declare those variables as `float` or `double` (not that you ever want to use floating-point types for serious money work, but for a toy program like this it's okay).

Answer (score 0):

Even though mathematically

*<sup>3</sup>/<sub>2</sub> betamount = moneywon*

and

*moneywon = <sup>3</sup>/<sub>2</sub> betamount*

have the same meaning you should know that the `=` (*assignment operator*) and `==` (*equality operator*) are different things thus

```
betamount * 1.5 = moneywon;
```

is not the same as

```
moneywon = betamount * 1.5;
```

and in fact, since `betamount * 1.5` is not an l*value* you can't assign to it and thus it cannot be at the left side of an assignment operator — I believe that the *l* in l*value* stands for *left* — so it's important to remember that the operands of the assignment operator are not commutative and exchanging them when possible<sup>1</sup>, gives a different meaning to the expression.

Nevertheless

```
moneywon == betamount * 1.5;
```

and

```
betamount * 1.5 == moneywon;
```

are equivalent like they are in mathematics.

But just like in mathematics, reading them *feels* different because you read such expressions like you read English and because of that humans prefer certain order in equality expressions anyway, but rigorously they are exactly the same.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>When both operands are l*values* which can perfectly be the case</sub>